# semanti-ui theming: site/globals/site.variables ignored?

Tags: gulp, semantic-ui

I'm trying to customize my semanti-ui theme.

In my site/globals/site.variables file i have

```
@fontName          : 'Poppins';
@headerFont        : 'Poppins-SemiBold', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

@primaryColor        : #06364b;
@secondaryColor      : #22b573;
```

and then in my site/globals/site.overrides I have

/* Latin only */

```
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Poppins Regular'), local('Poppins-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v5/HLBysyo0MQBO_7E-DWLwzg.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2212, U+2215;
}
```

i can see `gulp watch` successfully build the new css files.

When i inspect the files however, all the default fonts are still `Lato` and i can't see my primaryColor defined anywhere.

I think my config is right because the `@font-face` directive shows up in the css file.

It is just straight ignoring my `site.variables` file.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Try restarting your gulp task.

Comment: thanks but i did attempt this to no avail.

Comment: Did you solve this problem? Is your project a React app?